# Erro na compilação do compiz no slackware 14.2 64 bits com multlib

Tags: linux

Estou tentando compilar o compiz dentro do slackware 14.2 64 bits com multlib habilitado.
E o compilador retorna o seguinte erro:

> ```
> 3800/7907MB     0.13 0.06 0.08 1/527 9098slackware root /home/jjsantos/Downloads/compiz
> # sh compiz.SlackBuild 
> compiz-0.8.12.3/
> compiz-0.8.12.3/m4/
> compiz-0.8.12.3/m4/gettext.m4
> compiz-0.8.12.3/m4/iconv.m4
> compiz-0.8.12.3/m4/intlmacosx.m4
> compiz-0.8.12.3/m4/lib-ld.m4
> compiz-0.8.12.3/m4/lib-link.m4
> compiz-0.8.12.3/m4/lib-prefix.m4
> compiz-0.8.12.3/m4/libtool.m4
> compiz-0.8.12.3/m4/ltoptions.m4
> compiz-0.8.12.3/m4/ltsugar.m4
> compiz-0.8.12.3/m4/ltversion.m4
> compiz-0.8.12.3/m4/lt~obsolete.m4
> compiz-0.8.12.3/m4/nls.m4
> compiz-0.8.12.3/m4/po.m4
> compiz-0.8.12.3/m4/progtest.m4
> compiz-0.8.12.3/Makefile.am
> compiz-0.8.12.3/configure
> compiz-0.8.12.3/configure.ac
> compiz-0.8.12.3/aclocal.m4
> compiz-0.8.12.3/Makefile.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/compiz-cube.pc.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/compiz-scale.pc.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/compiz.pc.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/config.h.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/ABOUT-NLS
> compiz-0.8.12.3/AUTHORS
> compiz-0.8.12.3/COPYING
> compiz-0.8.12.3/ChangeLog
> compiz-0.8.12.3/INSTALL
> compiz-0.8.12.3/NEWS
> compiz-0.8.12.3/TODO
> compiz-0.8.12.3/compile
> compiz-0.8.12.3/config.guess
> compiz-0.8.12.3/config.rpath
> compiz-0.8.12.3/config.sub
> compiz-0.8.12.3/install-sh
> compiz-0.8.12.3/ltmain.sh
> compiz-0.8.12.3/missing
> compiz-0.8.12.3/COPYING.GPL
> compiz-0.8.12.3/COPYING.LGPL
> compiz-0.8.12.3/COPYING.MIT
> compiz-0.8.12.3/README.md
> compiz-0.8.12.3/autogen.sh
> compiz-0.8.12.3/intltool-extract.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/intltool-merge.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/intltool-update.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/include/
> compiz-0.8.12.3/include/Makefile.am
> compiz-0.8.12.3/include/compiz.h
> compiz-0.8.12.3/include/compiz-plugin.h
> compiz-0.8.12.3/include/compiz-core.h
> compiz-0.8.12.3/include/compiz-cube.h
> compiz-0.8.12.3/include/compiz-scale.h
> compiz-0.8.12.3/include/decoration.h
> compiz-0.8.12.3/include/Makefile.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/Makefile.am
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/Makefile.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/main.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/privates.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/object.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/core.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/texture.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/display.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/screen.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/window.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/event.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/paint.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/option.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/plugin.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/session.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/fragment.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/matrix.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/cursor.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/match.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/metadata.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/src/compiz-start.desktop.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/depcomp
> compiz-0.8.12.3/libdecoration/
> compiz-0.8.12.3/libdecoration/Makefile.am
> compiz-0.8.12.3/libdecoration/Makefile.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/libdecoration/libdecoration.pc.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/libdecoration/decoration.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/Makefile.am
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/Makefile.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/annotate.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/blur.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/clone.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/commands.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/cube.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/dbus.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/decoration.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/fade.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/fuse.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/glib.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/ini.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/inotify.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/matecompat.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/minimize.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/move.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/obs.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/place.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/png.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/regex.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/resize.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/rotate.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/scale.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/screenshot.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/svg.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/switcher.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/video.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/wall.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/wall_options.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/wall_options.h
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/water.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/wobbly.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/zoom.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/plugins/compiz-decorator
> compiz-0.8.12.3/images/
> compiz-0.8.12.3/images/Makefile.am
> compiz-0.8.12.3/images/Makefile.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/images/icon.png
> compiz-0.8.12.3/images/freedesktop.png
> compiz-0.8.12.3/images/hicolor_apps_16x16_compiz.png
> compiz-0.8.12.3/images/hicolor_apps_22x22_compiz.png
> compiz-0.8.12.3/images/hicolor_apps_24x24_compiz.png
> compiz-0.8.12.3/images/hicolor_apps_32x32_compiz.png
> compiz-0.8.12.3/images/hicolor_apps_scalable_compiz.svg
> compiz-0.8.12.3/images/hicolor_apps_16x16_gtk-decorator.png
> compiz-0.8.12.3/images/hicolor_apps_22x22_gtk-decorator.png
> compiz-0.8.12.3/images/hicolor_apps_24x24_gtk-decorator.png
> compiz-0.8.12.3/images/hicolor_apps_32x32_gtk-decorator.png
> compiz-0.8.12.3/images/hicolor_apps_48x48_gtk-decorator.png
> compiz-0.8.12.3/images/hicolor_apps_scalable_gtk-decorator.svg
> compiz-0.8.12.3/gtk/
> compiz-0.8.12.3/gtk/Makefile.am
> compiz-0.8.12.3/gtk/Makefile.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/gtk/window-decorator/
> compiz-0.8.12.3/gtk/window-decorator/Makefile.am
> compiz-0.8.12.3/gtk/window-decorator/Makefile.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/gtk/window-decorator/TODO
> compiz-0.8.12.3/gtk/window-decorator/gtk-window-decorator.c
> compiz-0.8.12.3/gtk/window-decorator/org.compiz-0.gwd.gschema.xml
> compiz-0.8.12.3/gtk/mate/
> compiz-0.8.12.3/gtk/mate/Makefile.am
> compiz-0.8.12.3/gtk/mate/Makefile.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/gtk/mate/compiz.desktop.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/Makefile.in.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/POTFILES.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/ar.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/as.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/be.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/bg.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/bn_IN.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/bn.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/ca.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/cs.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/da.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/de.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/el.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/en_GB.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/en_US.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/es.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/et.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/eu.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/fa.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/fi.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/fr.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/gl.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/gu.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/he.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/hi.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/hr.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/hu.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/id.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/it.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/ja.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/km.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/ko.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/lt.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/mk.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/ml_IN.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/mr.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/nb.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/nl.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/or.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/pa.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/pl.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/pt_BR.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/pt.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/ro.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/ru.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/sk.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/sl.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/sr.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/sv.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/ta.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/tr.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/uk.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/vi.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/zh_CN.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/zh_TW.po
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/ChangeLog
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/POTFILES.skip
> compiz-0.8.12.3/po/LINGUAS
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/Makefile.am
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/Makefile.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/core.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/annotate.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/blur.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/clone.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/commands.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/cube.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/dbus.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/decoration.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/fade.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/fs.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/glib.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/matecompat.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/ini.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/inotify.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/minimize.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/move.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/obs.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/place.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/png.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/regex.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/resize.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/rotate.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/scale.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/screenshot.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/svg.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/switcher.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/video.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/water.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/wobbly.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/wall.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/zoom.xml.in
> compiz-0.8.12.3/metadata/core.xml.in.in
> patching file metadata/cube.xml.in
> checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/ginstall -c
> checking whether build environment is sane... yes
> checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
> checking for gawk... gawk
> checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
> checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
> checking whether NLS is requested... yes
> checking for intltool >= 0.23... 0.51.0 found
> checking for intltool-update... /usr/bin/intltool-update
> checking for intltool-merge... /usr/bin/intltool-merge
> checking for intltool-extract... /usr/bin/intltool-extract
> checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
> checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
> checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
> checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
> checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
> checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.22.2
> checking for XML::Parser... ok
> checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
> checking for style of include used by make... GNU
> checking for gcc... gcc
> checking whether the C compiler works... yes
> checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
> checking for suffix of executables... 
> checking whether we are cross compiling... no
> checking for suffix of object files... o
> checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
> checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
> checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
> checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
> checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
> checking for library containing strerror... none required
> checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
> checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
> checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
> checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
> checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
> checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
> checking build system type... x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu
> checking host system type... x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu
> checking how to print strings... printf
> checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
> checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
> checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
> checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
> checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld
> checking if the linker (/usr/x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
> checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
> checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
> checking whether ln -s works... yes
> checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
> checking how to convert x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
> checking how to convert x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
> checking for /usr/x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
> checking for objdump... objdump
> checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
> checking for dlltool... dlltool
> checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
> checking for ar... ar
> checking for archiver @FILE support... @
> checking for strip... strip
> checking for ranlib... ranlib
> checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
> checking for sysroot... no
> checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
> checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
> checking for mt... mt
> checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
> checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
> checking for ANSI C header files... yes
> checking for sys/types.h... yes
> checking for sys/stat.h... yes
> checking for stdlib.h... yes
> checking for string.h... yes
> checking for memory.h... yes
> checking for strings.h... yes
> checking for inttypes.h... yes
> checking for stdint.h... yes
> checking for unistd.h... yes
> checking for dlfcn.h... yes
> checking for objdir... .libs
> checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
> checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
> checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
> checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
> checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
> checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
> checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
> checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
> checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
> checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
> checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
> checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
> checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
> checking whether to build static libraries... no
> checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
> checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
> checking sys/time.h usability... yes
> checking sys/time.h presence... yes
> checking for sys/time.h... yes
> checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
> checking for msgfmt... (cached) /usr/bin/msgfmt
> checking for gmsgfmt... (cached) /usr/bin/msgfmt
> checking for xgettext... (cached) /usr/bin/xgettext
> checking for msgmerge... (cached) /usr/bin/msgmerge
> checking for ld used by GCC... /usr/x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
> checking if the linker (/usr/x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
> checking for shared library run path origin... done
> checking for CFPreferencesCopyAppValue... no
> checking for CFLocaleCopyCurrent... no
> checking for GNU gettext in libc... yes
> checking whether to use NLS... yes
> checking where the gettext function comes from... libc
> checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
> checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
> checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
> checking for COMPIZ... yes
> checking for DECORATION... yes
> checking X11/extensions/XInput2.h usability... yes
> checking X11/extensions/XInput2.h presence... yes
> checking for X11/extensions/XInput2.h... yes
> checking for GL_CFLAGS... 
> checking for GL_LIBS... -lGL
> checking for xsltproc... xsltproc
> checking for LIBPNG... yes
> checking jpeglib.h usability... yes
> checking jpeglib.h presence... yes
> checking for jpeglib.h... yes
> checking GL/glu.h usability... yes
> checking GL/glu.h presence... yes
> checking for GL/glu.h... yes
> checking for GLIB... yes
> checking for DBUS... yes
> checking for DBUS_GLIB... yes
> checking sys/inotify.h usability... yes
> checking sys/inotify.h presence... yes
> checking for sys/inotify.h... yes
> checking for FUSE... yes
> checking for ANNOTATE... yes
> checking for LIBRSVG... yes
> checking which gtk+ version to compile against... 2.0
> checking for GTK_WINDOW_DECORATOR... yes
> checking for GSETTINGS... yes
> checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
> checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
> checking for MARCO... yes
> checking for COMPIZCONFIG... no
> checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
> configure: creating ./config.status
> config.status: creating compiz.pc
> config.status: creating compiz-cube.pc
> config.status: creating compiz-scale.pc
> config.status: creating Makefile
> config.status: creating src/Makefile
> config.status: creating libdecoration/Makefile
> config.status: creating libdecoration/libdecoration.pc
> config.status: creating include/Makefile
> config.status: creating plugins/Makefile
> config.status: creating images/Makefile
> config.status: creating gtk/Makefile
> config.status: creating gtk/window-decorator/Makefile
> config.status: creating gtk/mate/Makefile
> config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
> config.status: creating metadata/Makefile
> config.status: creating config.h
> config.status: executing depfiles commands
> config.status: executing libtool commands
> config.status: executing po-directories commands
> config.status: creating po/POTFILES
> config.status: setting ALL_LINGUAS in configure.in is obsolete
> config.status: creating po/Makefile
> config.status: executing include/compiz-common.h commands
> config.status: creating include/compiz-common.h
> config.status: executing po/stamp-it commands
>
> the following optional plugins will be compiled:
> glib:                      yes
> dbus:                      yes
> annotate:                  yes
> svg:                       yes
> inotify:                   yes
> fuse:                      yes
>
> and the following optional features will be used:
> gtk:                       yes (2.0)
> marco:                     yes
> mate:                      yes
> gwd gsettings support:     yes
> desktop menu entries:      no
>
> make  all-recursive
> make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/SBo/compiz-0.8.12.3'
> Making all in include
> make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/SBo/compiz-0.8.12.3/include'
> make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
> make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/SBo/compiz-0.8.12.3/include'
> Making all in src
> make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/SBo/compiz-0.8.12.3/src'
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo -c -o main.o main.c
> mv -f .deps/main.Tpo .deps/main.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT privates.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/privates.Tpo -c -o privates.o privates.c
> mv -f .deps/privates.Tpo .deps/privates.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT object.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/object.Tpo -c -o object.o object.c
> mv -f .deps/object.Tpo .deps/object.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT core.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/core.Tpo -c -o core.o core.c
> mv -f .deps/core.Tpo .deps/core.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT texture.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/texture.Tpo -c -o texture.o texture.c
> mv -f .deps/texture.Tpo .deps/texture.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT display.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/display.Tpo -c -o display.o display.c
> mv -f .deps/display.Tpo .deps/display.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT screen.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/screen.Tpo -c -o screen.o screen.c
> mv -f .deps/screen.Tpo .deps/screen.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT window.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/window.Tpo -c -o window.o window.c
> mv -f .deps/window.Tpo .deps/window.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT event.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/event.Tpo -c -o event.o event.c
> mv -f .deps/event.Tpo .deps/event.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT paint.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/paint.Tpo -c -o paint.o paint.c
> mv -f .deps/paint.Tpo .deps/paint.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT option.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/option.Tpo -c -o option.o option.c
> mv -f .deps/option.Tpo .deps/option.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT plugin.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/plugin.Tpo -c -o plugin.o plugin.c
> mv -f .deps/plugin.Tpo .deps/plugin.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT session.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/session.Tpo -c -o session.o session.c
> mv -f .deps/session.Tpo .deps/session.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT fragment.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/fragment.Tpo -c -o fragment.o fragment.c
> mv -f .deps/fragment.Tpo .deps/fragment.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT matrix.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/matrix.Tpo -c -o matrix.o matrix.c
> mv -f .deps/matrix.Tpo .deps/matrix.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT cursor.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/cursor.Tpo -c -o cursor.o cursor.c
> mv -f .deps/cursor.Tpo .deps/cursor.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT match.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/match.Tpo -c -o match.o match.c
> mv -f .deps/match.Tpo .deps/match.Po
> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/startup-notification-1.0 -I../include -I../include -DPLUGINDIR=\"/usr/lib64/compiz\" -DIMAGEDIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\" -DMETADATADIR=\"/usr/share/compiz\"   -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -MT metadata.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/metadata.Tpo -c -o metadata.o metadata.c
> mv -f .deps/metadata.Tpo .deps/metadata.Po
> /bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -export-dynamic -pthread  -o compiz main.o privates.o object.o core.o texture.o display.o screen.o window.o event.o paint.o option.o plugin.o session.o fragment.o matrix.o cursor.o match.o metadata.o -lX11 -lXcomposite -lXext -lXdamage -lXfixes -lXrandr -lXi -lXinerama -lXcursor -lICE -lSM -lxml2 -lstartup-notification-1 -lGL -lm -ldl -lm -ldl
> libtool: link: gcc -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -pthread -o compiz main.o privates.o object.o core.o texture.o display.o screen.o window.o event.o paint.o option.o plugin.o session.o fragment.o matrix.o cursor.o match.o metadata.o -Wl,--export-dynamic  /usr/lib64/libXcomposite.so /usr/lib64/libXdamage.so /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so /usr/lib64/libXi.so /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so /usr/lib64/libXcursor.so /usr/lib64/libXrender.so /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so /usr/lib64/libSM.so /usr/lib64/libICE.so /usr/lib64/libuuid.so /usr/lib64/libxml2.so -lz /usr/lib64/liblzma.so /usr/lib64/libstartup-notification-1.so /usr/lib64/libxcb-util.so /usr/lib64/libX11-xcb.so /usr/lib64/libGL.so -L/usr/X11R6/lib /usr/lib/libXext.so /usr/lib/libX11.so /usr/lib64/libXext.so /usr/lib64/libX11.so /usr/lib64/libxcb.so /usr/lib64/libXau.so /usr/lib64/libXdmcp.so -lm -ldl -pthread
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/X11R6/lib/libz.so when searching for -lz
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/X11R6/lib/libz.a when searching for -lz
> **/usr/lib/libXext.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> Makefile:503: recipe for target 'compiz' failed
> make[2]: *** [compiz] Error 1
> make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/SBo/compiz-0.8.12.3/src'
> Makefile:560: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
> make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/SBo/compiz-0.8.12.3'
> Makefile:465: recipe for target 'all' failed
> make: *** [all] Error 2**
> 966/7907MB      1.61 0.92 0.47 4/638 13394slackware root /home/jjsantos/Downloads/compiz
> # 
>
> 966/7907MB      1.61 0.92 0.47 4/638 13394slackware root /home/jjsantos/Downloads/compiz
> # uname -a
> Linux slackware 4.4.19 #2 SMP Mon Aug 22 14:37:39 CDT 2016 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
> 959/7907MB      1.51 0.97 0.50 3/636 13400slackware root /home/jjsantos/Downloads/compiz
> # ls /var/log/packages | grep multi
> gcc-5.3.0_multilib-x86_64-3alien
> gcc-g++-5.3.0_multilib-x86_64-3alien
> gcc-gfortran-5.3.0_multilib-x86_64-3alien
> gcc-gnat-5.3.0_multilib-x86_64-3alien
> gcc-go-5.3.0_multilib-x86_64-3alien
> gcc-java-5.3.0_multilib-x86_64-3alien
> gcc-objc-5.3.0_multilib-x86_64-3alien
> glibc-2.23_multilib-x86_64-1alien
> glibc-debug-2.23_multilib-x86_64-1alien
> glibc-i18n-2.23_multilib-x86_64-1alien
> glibc-profile-2.23_multilib-x86_64-1alien
> glibc-solibs-2.23_multilib-x86_64-1alien
> 957/7907MB      1.39 0.95 0.50 1/636 13407slackware root /home/jjsantos/Downloads/compiz
> #
> ```

Estranho que todas as outras libs o compilador buscou lib64, já essa ele foi buscar em lib:

> `/usr/lib/libXext.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format`

Answer (score 1):

Analisando o script.
E lendo man page slackbuid, descobrir que o problema era a ausencia da flag abaixo no script de compilação:

```
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib${LIBDIRSUFFIX}" \
```

Inserir a flag após:

```
CFLAGS="$SLKCFLAGS" \
CXXFLAGS="$SLKCFLAGS" \
```

E problema resolvido.

Comment: Ok, farei.

Grato